# My textbook says one and the wikipedia and undergrad professor on quora other, which is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, volume

I am learning about thermodynamics(1st law), and in my textbook it's stated that heat does not transfer from the isothermal process to the surrounding, but the undergrad professor(from quora, on some different question, but mentioned this) says it does and I have read the same on Wikipedia. If there is work done on the system, in order to keep temperature constant and therefore internal energy that heat must leave the system, right?

Comment: Which textbook is this?  Can you include the exact text in question, including the context?  The statement in the textbook sure sounds wrong, but perhaps there's some conditions in the text that make it more sensible.

Comment: In an isothermal process, if positive work is done by the system on the surroundings, heat must flow into the system.  If positive work is done by the surroundings on the system, heat must flow out of the system.

Comment: It's actually a question from the exercise book but that is pretty much the same as a statement because the question goes like this: which of these does NOT apply to the isothermal process; a) heat transfer from body to surrounding and vice versa b) internal energy of the gas is constant c) work is done d) product of pressure and volume is constant. It's written by Labor and Paudan(Croatian authors).

Comment: Does the question pertain to the two isothermal portions of the ideal Carnot cycle? If so, all four options are true. Heat is transferred, the internal energy is constant, work is done, and PV=nRT is constant. Dumb textbook.

Comment: No, just got to the 1st law of thermodynamics. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @jeaq Textbook answer is correct. Because it is about process not a complete work-heat cycle. So in a process either heat is transfer to surrounding or transfer from surrounding, not both in single process.